# ion-content not showing after add ion-side-menu

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have learned 3 days create mobile apps with ionic framework.

I originally made with html and css for each page, and in file index.html I want to add a side menu. then I add the code , and finally it worked ..

but, I get problems.  ..  does not appear under the header..

I do not know why the content does not appear, because before I add the , the content appears.

this my code index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-header bar-dark">
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
    <div class="h1 title">23 Desember 20014</div>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right"> </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
</ion-side-menu-content> 

<ion-side-menu side="right">
  <a menu-close href="#/home" class="item">Home</a>
  <a menu-close href="#/home" class="item">Home</a>
  <a menu-close href="#/home" class="item">Home</a>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

<!-- NOT APPEAR -->
<ion-content>
<div class="row green">
  <div class="col">Saldo</div>
  <div class="col price">9,735,000</div>
</div>
<div class="row light-green">
  <div class="col">Income</div>
  <div class="col price">3,550,000</div>
</div>
<div class="row pink expense-now">
  <div class="col"><strong>Expense</strong></div>
</div>
</ion-content> 
<!-- NOT APPEAR -->

</body>
</html>
```

and this my code app.js :

```
// Ionic Starter App

angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
   if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
   }
   if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
   }
  });
})

function ContentController($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
}
```

please help me for this case, 
thank's in advance,
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for side menu (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) and the demos (http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tcIGK), it looks like your content needs to be *inside* the ion-side-menus tag, not outside as you have it here.

Stackoverflow won't let me submit the CodePen url w/o code so I'm adding code just to get it to shut up.

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Center content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="ContentController">
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>

  <!-- Right menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, you're right.

so, i change content to inside ion-side-menus and it's work..